# Sass add parent selector after current ( selector& )

Tags: sass, bem

I have BEM structure like this (*but the question not about BEM*):

```
.form-element  { //.form-element
    ...
    &__control { //.form-element__control
        ...
    }
    //now I want to have specific rule: textarea.form-element__control
    textarea& { // < here is an error

    }
    //it works like this:
    textarea & {

    }
}
```

I think, i'm missing something tiny, like a bracers, or something similar, if it's doable at all.

The question in the code comments :)

Comment: LESS handles this particular feature better than Sass.

Comment: Well, this particular feature is a way too small reason to move to Less. :)

Comment: I absolutely agree, which is why I didn't tell you to switch to LESS. I just commented because it's worth noting, given that the syntax you used works as-is in LESS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow my example this will achieve what you are after.

Use the interpolation method `#{ }` and combine it with the `@at-root` function

```
@at-root textarea#{&} {
    display: none;
}
```

My example here

```
.contact-block {
    @at-root textarea#{&} {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Compiles to

```
textarea.contact-block {
    display: none;
}
```

So this is what yours would look like

```
.form-element {
    &__control {
        @at-root textarea#{&} {
            display: none;
        }
    }
}
```

Compiling to

```
textarea.form-element__control {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I've edited my answer to illustrate what you are trying to achieve using your classes.

Comment: I just needed #{&} this voodoo! :) Never thought of using it that way :) Previously I only used it for dynamic class name building in mixins.

Comment: Using just #{&} without the @at-root will compile something completely different